# How to filter data based on coordinate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview

In my app, I have a lot of locations and on the basis of current location i need to filter the results and display only those which are in 5 mile radius.
Is there a way to achieve this??

Thanks,

Comment: trigonometry. Look up distance between points. Other than that ic annot help, because you haven;t told us how your data is stored. how you are searching on it (nspredicate?), stuff like that. A bit more information would help.

Answer (score 2):

CLLocation has distanceFromLocation, can be called like

```
CLLocation dist = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function. This will help you.

```
-(void)distanceBetween{


double latitude1 = [merchant.latitude doubleValue];
double longitude1 = [merchant.longitude doubleValue];

NSUserDefaults *userLocation = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
float lat = [userLocation floatForKey:@"latitude"];
float lon = [userLocation floatForKey:@"longitude"];


CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude1 longitude:longitude1];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];

CLLocationDistance distanceTo = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"locaA is %f", locA);
NSLog(@"locaB is %f", locB);
NSLog(@"locdistnace is %f", distanceTo);
[[self distance] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f miles", distanceTo/1609.34]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, haven't tested it though:

```
- (NSArray *)filterArrayOfLocations:(NSArray *)array byDistance:(CLLocationDistance)distance toCurrentLocation:(CLLocation*)currentLocation
{
    NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:(CLLocation *)evaluatedObject] < distance;
    }]];
    return filteredArray;
}
```